# XPath: how to get a part of value

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

XML:

```
<strong class="pull-right ng-binding">Found: 1258</strong>
```

Need to get only value: "1258" without word "Found", cuz it's multilanguge project, and i cant use locales.

Now I stopped on this code:

```
"//strong[contains(text(),': "+value+"')]"
```

But contains works not correctly with asserts, and I need something with normalize-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [`substring-after()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/substring-after):

```
substring-after(//strong, ": ")
```

Comment: Just i think so : `substring-after(//strong, ':')`

Comment: @splash58 yeah, `text()` is unnecessary. Thanks.